# Access a javascript variable in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

So here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a client facing page that loads, and when that happens I automatically run a series of 4 quick tests, if any of those tests fail I update the HCresults variable.

.aspx

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" src="script/XmlHttp.js?vers=<%=VersionInfo %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="client_scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var HCresults = "";
    </script>
  </asp:Content>
```

I want to access the value of HCresults after the page finishes loading from my code behind page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you need this in a server form post?  Do you have an event handler defined?

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about either of those. Today is my second day of dealing with web-dev in my internship. I don't have an event handler defined though, I can tell you that

Answer (score 1):

You can write a webmethod in your code behind;
pseudo code:

```
public static var HCresultsCS;
[webmethod]
public static void grabHCresults(var HCresultsfromJS)
{
HCresultsCS= HCresultsfromJS;
}
```

make an AJAX post to this webmethod with HCresults you're setting on a test failure as parameter;

Access the HCresultsCS from CS now. Check for nulls! I can't comment
This link might be helpful:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not using JS, you can store the value in a `hiddenfield` however to retrieve in C#. Make sure that you set the attribute `runat = "server"` for the control. I should also mention you'll use `element.value = value` to assign the value.

Comment: I think you may have it backwards? I'm trying to access a variable in my .aspx file from my .cs file

Comment: @jlee I realized that now. Answer is updated with the right context.

Comment: where does that value assignment occur? I assume you're talking about the value of the hiddenfield?

Comment: @jlee Yea, I'd have the assignment actually happen after the testing is over and you have issues. Yes to the second question, `document.getElementById('hiddenfieldname').value = HCresults`.